# How to make a calculation formula using rank in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: math, flutter, dart, symbols, rank

I have a formula like this: `NPV = Value / (1 + Rate of discount) ^Time`. Then I create logic in Flutter using `double` like this:

[image]

And I get the error of symbols `^` for rank formula. How can I complete the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

nVP = value * math.pow(1 + rate, time);
```